# Location based whitelisting of IP's on nginx webservers behind Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, x-forwarded-for

I run nginx webservers behind an elastic load balancer in AWS.
The real IP is got through X-Forwarded-For.
The issue faced is how to use this to deny all and whitelist only specific sources for particular locations.

Something like: 
location /test/ {
include /etc/nginx/allowed-XForwardedFor.conf;
deny all;
}

Can I catch the X-Forwarded-For IP's with a variable and then use it in the conf file or in some-way use it with the allow option in locations or do it with the help of an if conditional?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [nginx realip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html), and then you don't have to worry about the X-Forwarded-For header; you can just act on IP addresses as if the load balancer wasn't there.

A sample configuration:

```
http {
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        set_real_ip_from 172.19.0.0/16; # Netblock for my ELB's
```

Comment: I already use the above config in the http {} block but when I try doing a source whitelist on the basis of location like: location /test/ { allow ip; deny all;}   it does not work. Hence I was wondering if I could use x-forwarded-for as a variable directly in the location directive. Is there anything else I should be doing or checking?

Comment: Well, you should ask your real question first. It will save you a lot of time :)

Comment: Hey, apologize for not being clear enough to be understood :)